# Closing keyboard takes to the top of the page safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css

One my webpage I have a bootstrap model opened which has a form with two text boxes and few buttons. When I touch text box keyboard opens which is what I would expect but when I press done (on top of open keyboard) to close keyboard, safari on iPhone it scrolls all the way to the top of the page. This is causing model to loose focus and scroll events are being sent to underlying main page. So the question is, is there any way to get keyboard close event so that I can override this behaviour or any other way prevent it from happening. It's only happening on iPhone chrome and iPhone safari. It works fine on android chrome.

Comment: It turns out this issue is related to https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17695. I tried workarounds mentioned in this thread, nothing worked. So if any of you have any other workarounds I would love to hear about it.